# File Downloading

Tags: download, converters

We are working on our *converter* site. and we want users to download their converted file. But audio files and other files are just playing on the browser, How can we set all **Video/Audio formats downloadable** (not just because the browser supports the player for the formats). THANKS.

Comment: Your question is missing some crucial details, like what platform and web server you are using. It is also not entirely clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should check the MIME types. I think if you set it as [binary](http://mime-type.net/application/x-binary/), it will get downloaded, not played by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to put the file(s) into an archive server side then attach the archive to the response.  That way you avoid client playback and potentially decrease download time.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is, as most sites do, just show the link and instruct the user to right click and select download. I'd go with other options (as proposed, like looking into the MIME types), but it is still another possibility.